# Error when applying readRDS function to Arvados Collection connection in R

Tags: r

I get an error when I try to read a **R** object from a **RDS** file which is located on an [Arvados](https://arvados.org/) platform. First, I use the following code to connect to Arvados and get a file listing:

```
library('ArvadosR')

# Read ARVADOS_API_TOKEN and ARVADOS_API_HOST
readRenviron("~/.config/arvados/arv.conf")

# Connect to Arvados
arv = Arvados$new()

# Get collection object
coll = Collection$new(arv, "<collection_uuid>")

# List collection content
coll$getFileListing()
```

When I read a tab delimited file `xyz.txt` with

`df.a = read.delim(coll$get("xyz.txt")$connection("r"))`

it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to read an RDS file `abc.RDS` with

`df.b = readRDS(coll$get("abc.RDS")$connection("r"))`

I get the following **error**:

```
Error in readRDS(coll$get("abc.RDS")$connection("r")) : 
   unknown input format
```

Reading `abc.RDS` from a local drive works fine. According to the help page, `readRDS` accepts "a connection or the name of the file where the **R** object is saved to or read from".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could make it work with `readRDS(gzcon(coll$get("abc.RDS")$connection("rb")))`.

In `help(readRDS)` I noticed this paragraph:

"Compression is handled by the connection opened when `file` is a file name, so is only possible when `file` is a connection if handled by the connection. So e.g. `url` connections will need to be wrapped in a call to `gzcon`."